# Getting wrong result from database - Wrong counting for a specific field in records using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to count number of a word "Saturday" that's been stored in database records using PHP.
It's not counting correctly.I have in that column only three records : Saturday Saturday Sunday
When I print out $row['Repeating'] it displays all records as Saturday Saturday Saturday where's the counter for Saturday must be 2 and counter for Sunday is one.My counter is not working correctly
The out put I got for counter Saturday is 3 and for Sunday is 3. I can't spot the error.
Any idea I would appreciate it.

Thank you

```
        $numberofWcounters = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $dementiacounter1 = 1;
        // count Saturday.
         $counterSaturday=0;
        // count sunday
          $counterSunday=0;
        while( $counter <= $numberofWcounters)
         {


            if ($row['Day'] ='Saturday')

             {
                $counterSaturday++;
             }
           if ($row['Repeating'] ='Sunday')

             {
                $counterSunday++;
             }

             $counter++;
        }
          echo $row['Repeating'] ;
          echo "<br />The number of Saturday for repeating question are :   " . $$counterSaturday ;
```

Comment: One quick thing I noticed is that you should be using '==' instead of the assignment operator '='.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not appear to be iterating over the result set, which means you are looping 3 times over the same row (which is the first in the result set)

You'll have to use mysqli_fetch or equivalent to make sure you actually access each of the different results your query generated.

```
$result->bind_result( $day, $repeating );

while( $result->fetch() ) {
  // in every iteration of this loop, $day is $row['Day'] and $repeating is $row['Repeating'] of a new row
  if ($day =='Saturday')
  {
    $counterSaturday++;
   }
   if ($repeating == 'Sunday')
   {
    $counterSunday++;
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be something like this. (Replace your current while loop with this)

Comment: can you give me example please